# Can I glue two objects together such that they deform instead of separating?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, parent

Bit of a weird question, I have the femur and the pelvis bones as objects (actual meshes of these bones not armatures). I want to take pictures of these bones in different positions and I have all of the rotational axes set to easily reposition. I would like to attach a muscle (also an object) between the femur and the hip so that when the femur moves the muscle between the femur and the hip deform. I was wondering if there was an easy (or hard) way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, could you please show some pictures?